# Datepicker selected value always goes on the first textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to create a form in which elements are added dynamically by cloning existing elements in the form.
Now the problem i am facing is when i cloned textbox which has class "datepicker".When I select the date from cloned element it's selected value shows in the first element from which I cloned it.

Here is the code:

```
$(copiedDiv).find('input[type="text"]').filter('.datepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
```

and in document.ready I tried this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

and this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").each(function(){$(this).datepicker()});
});
```

but both gives the same result.
Plz guide me. . Thanx

Comment: how are you trying to access/set the selected value?

Comment: You should initialize `.datepikcet();` on new cloned DOM element, because all jQuery initialized on load, wont work on new DOM elements, you should initializes new.

Comment: Wouldn't first line of code initializing the new cloned element?
$(copiedDiv).find('input[type="text"]').filter('.datepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are creating input elements dynamically by cloning original div, here `.clone()` will do shallow cloning and not deep cloning and hence input box instance will be same always and hence datepicker will refer to original input box.

You can remove `id` and `class` of the copied input box and then apply `datepicker` on it.

Please see below jquery code :

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
      var copiedDiv = $('#container').clone();

      var input = $(copiedDiv).find('input[type="text"]');

      $(copiedDiv).removeAttr('id');

      $(input).removeAttr('id').removeClass('datepicker hasDatepicker').val('');

      $(input).datepicker();             

      $('#container').after(copiedDiv);
    });

  // bind datepicker to existing input with class="datepicker"
  $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/bepzbqpo/17/)**

Comment: I have assigned them different id and name. .

Comment: You can see my jsfiddle link is working as expected, can you please share your code and jsfiddle link?

Comment: Yes your jsfiddle working perfectly . . but in my situation i can not remove the id . . instead i am changing the id of the element, so that each element got unique id. . is id is really matters in this case?

Comment: Not necessary to remove `id` but it should be unique when you assign new one. But you need to remove `class="hasDatepicker"` before assigning datepicker.

Comment: Yes ids are unique and i think this line will remove the class:
$(copiedDiv).find('input[type="text"]').filter('.datepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();

Comment: I think instead of using `find().filter()` you should use `find()` only like `$(copiedDiv).find('.datepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();` and try

Comment: I have used the line you suggested but still the same result . .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59167/discussion-between-bhushan-kawadkar-and-user2517610).