# dynamic form datepicker jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I tried to create a dynamic form. Im not sure why the datepicker cant be clicked. Datepicker only work on first row. I already try few other code but no luck. The code is provided below. I excluded the PHP code because it only consist of code for insert into database. My target is to store the dynamic form into database.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
            });
        });
        $(function()
        {
            $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var controlForm = $('.controls .d1:first'),
                    currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
                    newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);
                newEntry.find('input').val('');
                controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
                    .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
                    .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                    .html('<span class="fa fa-minus"></span>');
            }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)
            {
                $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="" name="loginin">
<div class="controls">
    <div class="d1">
        <div class="entry input-group">
            <input list="pronama"  name="proPlace[]" type="text" placeholder="Place" class="form-control">
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" class="form-control" name="date[]">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Sign In</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694306/use-jquery-datepicker-on-dynamically-created-fields

Comment: tried the answer in the possible duplicate but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the datepicker with each creation, like so:

```
newEntry.removeAttr('id');
$(".datepicker", newEntry)
   .removeAttr('id')
   .removeClass('datepicker hasDatepicker')
   .datepicker({
       dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
   });
```

making the new entry's input a date picker, the removal of the `hasDatepicker` class is needed for this to work, because you clone the input, the class is in the cloned element too.

here's a jsfiddle: [adding dynamic datepickers](https://jsfiddle.net/5ct8q0ov/1/)

EDIT:
updated the fiddler, the reason only the first input was updated on selecting a date, is because it's a cloned element, containing the same id as the original, so when looking for the id of the datepicker, it stumbles upon the one.

the fix was described here.
[Datepicker selected value always goes on the first textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258256/datepicker-selected-value-always-goes-on-the-first-textbox)

Comment: i had try this. it work but changes only happen for first row even if i click on second row.

Comment: Fixed the answer.